# vscode running tasks in sequence in a virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv, vscode-tasks

### Question

How do I get a vscode task's command to run in a python virtual environment/shell created by another task?

### Example

I'm trying to run a couple of tasks in sequence using vscode.

1. The first task will run the command `pipenv shell`.
2. The second task needs to be run in the virtual environment created by the first task.

The second task will only run if I exit the virtual environment created by the first task manually by running `exit` in the created shell.
Presumably because it is waiting for the first task to complete - but the first task is only complete when the process ends (when I run `exit`).

### tasks.json

```json
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "first task",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "pipenv shell",
      "presentation": {
        "panel": "shared",
      },
    },
    {
      "label": "second task",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "<some_command>",
      "presentation": {
        "panel": "shared",
      },
    },
    {
      "label": "combine tasks",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo hello",
      "dependsOrder": "sequence",
      "dependsOn": ["first task", "second task"],
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `venv` virtual environments? VSC will activate the VirtEnv for you if you select the correct python interpreter

Comment: @rioV8 - I think OP is having the same issue I am - if I create a new terminal manually in vscode, it will run it in the .venv. That is configured. However task shell commands are not inheriting the same environment... so I too have been trying to chain commands because I can't for the life of me figure out how to have the venv active for my command-line commands.

Comment: @MandMBen have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

The first task to do is activate the virtual environment for the correct terminal you use (Powershell, cmd, bash, ....)

Then run the additional terminal tasks sequentially.

I used Powershell and Python venv for virtual environment

I used these tasks (no terminal was active) and they run in the terminal variant with the `> Executing task`, `Terminal will be reused by tasks` texts.

```json
    {
      "label": "Activate python venv",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "c:/Project/Python/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1",
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "pip list",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "pip list",
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "combine Python",
      "type": "shell",
      "dependsOrder": "sequence",
      "dependsOn": ["Activate python venv", "pip list"],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
```

It will list all the packages installed in the virtual environment.